# Order of zero of f/g

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that $f$ has zero of order j at $x_0$ and g has zero of order $k$. Let $k<j$ What will be the order of $f/g$? 
I'm having a bit of trouble doing this one.  I know that by l'hospital, 
$\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)} = \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{g^{(k)}(x_0)} = 0$
However I'm not sure how to keep going from here.

Comment: don't you need $k<j$ or something?

Comment: yeah $k<j$ thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Then the order of zero of $f/g$ at $x_0$ will just be $j-k$

Comment: How do we show that?

Comment: Well you can write $f(x)=(x-x_0)^jf_0(x)$ and $g(x)=(x-x_0)^kg_0(x)$ for some functions $f_0$ and $g_0$ that do not vanish at $x_0$. So $f/g = (x-x_0)^{(j-k)}f_0/g_0$ where &f_0/g_0$ doesn't vanish at $x_0$